# AndroidKeyStore cannot generate certificate

Tags: java, android, security, provider, android-keystore

I have been trying to solve this issue regarding `AndroidKeyStore`. My app seems to not getting `Android` native provider for `NONEwithRSA` signing algorithm. This is the code reference:

```
Calendar startDate = Calendar.getInstance();
Calendar endDate = Calendar.getInstance();
endDate.add(Calendar.YEAR, 30);

KeyPairGeneratorSpec keyPairGeneratorSpec = new KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
                        .setAlias("aliasName")
                        .setSubject(new X500Principal("CN=aliasName"))
                        .setSerialNumber(BigInteger.TEN)
                        .setStartDate(startDate.getTime())
                        .setEndDate(endDate.getTime())
                        .build();

KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(keyPairGeneratorSpec);
keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
```

Once `generateKeyPair()` gets called, I got the following exception stack trace.

```
Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: java.security.ProviderException: No provider for NONEwithRSA
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSignature.engineSign(:com.google.android.gms@12673012@12.6.73 (020408-194189626):6)
    at java.security.Signature$SignatureImpl.engineSign(Signature.java:672)
    at java.security.Signature.sign(Signature.java:381)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509.X509Util.calculateSignature(X509Util.java:248)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator.generate(X509V3CertificateGenerator.java:434)
    at com.android.org.bouncycastle.x509.X509V3CertificateGenerator.generate(X509V3CertificateGenerator.java:412)
    at android.security.AndroidKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(AndroidKeyPairGenerator.java:133)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.security.ProviderException: No provider for NONEwithRSA
    at java.security.Signature$SignatureImpl.getSpi(Signature.java:734)
    at java.security.Signature$SignatureImpl.engineInitSign(Signature.java:692)
    at java.security.Signature.initSign(Signature.java:343)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.CryptoUpcalls.rawSignDigestWithPrivateKey(:com.google.android.gms@12673012@12.6.73 (020408-194189626):11)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.EVP_DigestSignFinal(Native Method)
    at com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSignature.engineSign(:com.google.android.gms@12673012@12.6.73 (020408-194189626):2)
    ... 32 more
```

No solution is found related to my issue. Does anyone have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace the line with
`KeyPairGenerator keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");`

As it is showing in logs that No provider for NONEwithRSA

**Updated**

You can try the below code for generating key pair in Androidkeystore and android version should be greater than 18

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA", "AndroidKeyStore");
           // generator.initialize(spec);
            generator.initialize(new KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    alias ,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_SIGN | KeyProperties.PURPOSE_VERIFY)
                    .setDigests(KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA256,
                            KeyProperties.DIGEST_SHA512)
                    .setCertificateSubject(new X500Principal("CN=aliasName" ))
                    .setCertificateNotBefore(start.getTime())
                    .setCertificateNotAfter(end.getTime())
                    .setCertificateSerialNumber(BigInteger.ONE)
                    .setSignaturePaddings(KeyProperties.SIGNATURE_PADDING_RSA_PKCS1)
                    .build());
            KeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
```

Comment: I'm sorry to confuse you with all the constants. I edited all the constants to actual value used. The odd part is that my device is still not getting `Android` native `Provider`.

Comment: I even replaced `"AndroidKeyStore"` with `keystore.getProvider()` and it's still not working. What I got wasn't `NoSuchProviderException` so I guess my device actually has `AndroidKeyStore` as one of the providers but NONEwithRSA is not supported, which is different from what stated here: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#SupportedSignatures

Comment: I would appreciate if you could add explanation for the `KeyGenParameterSpec` part and how it would solve the issue.

Comment: You have to provide the digest in KeyGenParameterSpec. It can be sha256 or sha512. As you have not specified any digest it is taking null.

Comment: What you wanted to do with Keypair?